# Zend Server CE, After Uninstall, localhost doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, localhost, mamp, zend-server-ce

This is odd...

I installed Zend Server to test it out. Turns out I don't like it and I wanted to go back to MAMP. But after the Zend Server CE uninstall, "localhost" no longer works. I can only access MAMP from 127.0.0.1

Frustrating and I'm not liking it at all.

Any ideas?

**hosts:**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost

127.0.0.1 mydomain.loc www.mydomain.loc
```

**nslookup says:**

```
Server:     64.59.160.13
Address:    64.59.160.13#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   localhost
Address: 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: What's in `/etc/hosts`? I'm curious about what you didn't like about ZSCE. For me, it's by far the better PHP application stack

Comment: can you print your host file? `/private/etc/hosts`

Comment: What does your Apache vhost configuration look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was told by a college that sometimes the only thing you can do to wake up port 80 on the Mac is to enable the built in web server and then disable it again.

So I did that and all is well.

Comment: Can you direct me to this talking college of wisdom (we call them Universities in Aus)? ;)

Comment: HAHA! That's hilarious... "colleague"

Answer (score 0):

you mention `127.0.0.1` which is a IPv6 address. Many (all?) modern operating systems are configured to resolve `localhost` using IPv6 to `::1`. My assumption would be that your MAMP setup is not listening via IPv6. Try opening http://[::1]/ if that works there is an error in our resolve configuration, if not (what I expect) you have to configure your web server to either lsiten to ::1 or any device.

This can be done in httpd.conf using

```
Listen 80
```

to listen on all devices, port 80 or

```
Listen [::1]:80
```

to listen to localhost via IPv6 only. Mind not having conflicting VHost entries etc.

Comment: johannes, thanks for replying. There's nothing wrong with MAMP. It's a fresh install that has ALWAYS run without an issue. It only started happening after the install/uninstall of Zend Server, and changing the ports within that httpd.conf file .

Comment: nslookup says:
Server:  64.59.160.13
Address: 64.59.160.13#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: localhost
Address: 127.0.0.1

Comment: @johannes Did you mean "IPv4" in that first line (referring to `127.0.0.1`)?